# Is asking about the relative merits of various releases for main or meta?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Is asking about the relative merits of various releases for main or meta? or both? or Neither?

Thanks

Comment: I would certainly make a link only answer to the Release Notes/Change logs.

Answer (score 3):

It's certainly not Meta. Meta is really just for things about Ask Ubuntu, the site and its community.

Whether it's really answerable in a sense that we'd welcome on the main site, it's probably either a bit too broad (a changelogs for all the packages are available). If you could limit the scope of the question to something that is a bit more atomic, you might have an answerable question.

If you updated your question here to include an example of the question you'd be considering asking, I can update my answer to offer further guidance.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize the last part of my comment didn't take... but the question I would ask would be something along the lines of: "why would someone use 13.10 over 12.04 and vice versa?" This seems to me like a bit of a discussion question, rather than a question that could have a specific answer